# Opengl render to texture, but the texture is null

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to render to a texture, then to render it onto a square. But the result is a pink square.

I create the textures, framebuffers etc.

```
texture renderTexture = texture();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 1000, 600, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

unsigned int fb;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fb);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture.getId(), 0);
```

Then on the game loop I call this:

```
show(fb);
showMenu(renderTexture.getId());
```

```
void game::show(unsigned int fb){

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 600);

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
   glEnd();

   // Render a pyramid consists of 4 triangles
   glLoadIdentity();                  // Reset the model-view matrix
   glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);  // Move left and into the screen
}

void game::showMenu(unsigned int renderTexture){

    bindWindowAsRenderTarget();
    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 600);

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glOrtho(0.0, 1000.0, 0.0, 600.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture);
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,2.0);
        glVertex3f(-2.0,2.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(-2.0,-2.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(2.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(2.0,-2.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(2.0,2.0);
        glVertex3f(2.0,2.0,0.0);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
}

void game::bindWindowAsRenderTarget(){
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 600);
}
```

And this is the texture class:

```
#include "texture.h"

texture::texture(){
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
}

texture::~texture(){
    glDeleteTextures(1, &id);
}

void texture::loadImage(const char* filename){
    SDL_Surface* img = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img->w, img->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, img->pixels);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
}

unsigned int texture::getId(){
    return id;
}
```

I don't have any errors when compiling...

Is there anything I'm missing?
Does someone know how to solve it?

Many thanks.

Comment: `texture renderTexture = texture()` that looks very wrong. If you want it to live on the heap then it should be `texture renderTexture();`. But I guess the major problem is that the texture goes out of scope before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
texture renderTexture = texture();
```

You are missing the `new` keyword. This is keeping your texture constructor from being called, which appears to be performing your texture generation.

replace it with

`texture* renderTexture = new texture();`

Comment: But then this error appears: error: conversion from ‘texture*’ to non-scalar type ‘texture’ requested

Comment: That's because he forgot to say that you have to use pointers (`texture* renderTexture = new texture();` for this... But if this is new to you, I recommend reading a good C++ tutorial before starting with OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks, I just forget it. I'm not new to c++, but this is my first "project". But the problem stills there... And the program crashes when I run it...

Comment: Then please provide a minimal but complete example of your code. Atm, it is unclear how this code parts are related to each other. And set a breakpoint in the destructor to see if your texture gets deleted too early. Then make sure that you have proper filters set.

Comment: Now that I look at it in more detail: Is your quad visible at all? With a visible area from 0 to 1000 (or 0 to 600), a quad from -2 to 2 sounds rather small. The depth values also look strange. You draw at z = -5 but set the projection to a visible range from -1 to 1. And why are your texture coordinates going from 0 to 2?

Comment: Yes, I see it, and it is very big, but it is pink... and should be the clear color of the last render...